# Java get String CompareTo as a comparator object

Tags: java, string, object, comparator

I would like to sort and binary search a static array of strings via the String.CompareTo comparator.

The problem is that both sorting, and binary searching requires that a Comparator object be passed in -- So how do I pass in the built in string comparator?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `Arrays` class has versions of `sort()` and `binarySearch()` which don't require a `Comparator.` For example, you can use [the version of `Arrays.sort()` which just takes an array of objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object[])). These methods call the `compareTo()` method of the objects in the array.

Answer (score 50):

You may write your own comparator

```
public class ExampleComparator  implements Comparator<String> {
  public int compare(String obj1, String obj2) {
    if (obj1 == obj2) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (obj1 == null) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (obj2 == null) {
        return 1;
    }
    return obj1.compareTo(obj2);
  }
}
```

Comment: `Comparator` is a generic type, so `ExampleComparator` should probably implement `Comparator<String>` to avoid warnings.

Comment: For string comparator, keep in mind to lowercase (or uppercase) string before compare them otherwise you should get this order A-Za-z

Comment: Need to implement equals() too.

Comment: Are you sure that you are supposed to return `-1` in case that `obj1==null && obj2==null`, though?

Comment: Based on @towi's comment on Nov 24 '17: If `obj1 == obj2` then it is `true` and thus resulting `0` when both of them are equals `null`!

Answer (score 48):

Solution for Java 8 based on [java.util.Comparator.comparing(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-):

```
Comparator<String> c = Comparator.comparing(String::toString);
```

or

```
Comparator<String> c = Comparator.comparing((String x) -> x);
```

Comment: Or Comparator.comparing(Function.identity())

Comment: Or `String::compareTo`  
`Comparator<String> c = String::compareTo`  
I think inlining is more readable than creating a variable for it: `myListOfText.sort(String::compareTo);`

Answer (score 20):

Ok this is a few years later but with java 8 you can use Comparator.naturalOrder():

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder--

From javadoc:

```
static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Comparator<T> naturalOrder()
```

Returns a comparator that compares Comparable objects in natural order.
The returned comparator is serializable and throws NullPointerException when comparing null.

Comment: Links to potential answers are always welcome, but please add most important parts here in case link gets removed.

Answer (score 14):

If you do find yourslef needing a `Comparator`, and you already use [`Guava`](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), you can use [`Ordering.natural()`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#natural()).

Answer (score 11):

This is a generic `Comparator` for any kind of `Comparable` object, not just `String`:

```
package util;

import java.util.Comparator;

/**
 * The Default Comparator for classes implementing Comparable.
 *
 * @param <E> the type of the comparable objects.
 *
 * @author Michael Belivanakis (michael.gr)
 */
public final class DefaultComparator<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Comparator<E>
{
    @SuppressWarnings( "rawtypes" )
    private static final DefaultComparator<?> INSTANCE = new DefaultComparator();

    /**
     * Get an instance of DefaultComparator for any type of Comparable.
     *
     * @param <T> the type of Comparable of interest.
     *
     * @return an instance of DefaultComparator for comparing instances of the requested type.
     */
    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> Comparator<T> getInstance()
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Comparator<T> result = (Comparator<T>)INSTANCE;
        return result;
    }

    private DefaultComparator()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public int compare( E o1, E o2 )
    {
        if( o1 == o2 )
            return 0;
        if( o1 == null )
            return 1;
        if( o2 == null )
            return -1;
        return o1.compareTo( o2 );
    }
}
```

How to use with `String`:

```
Comparator<String> stringComparator = DefaultComparator.getInstance();
```

Comment: @Sharcoux I see!  C-:=

Comment: Could be nice to add the following code to that class:

public static <T extends Comparable<T>> Comparator<T> getReversedInstance()
    {
        return Collections.reverseOrder((Comparator<T>) getInstance());
    }

Answer (score 10):

Again, don't need the comparator for `Arrays.binarySearch(Object[] a, Object key)` so long as the types of objects are comparable, but with lambda expressions this is now way easier.

Simply replace the comparator with the method reference: `String::compareTo`

E.g.:

```
Arrays.binarySearch(someStringArray, "The String to find.", String::compareTo);
```

You could also use

```
Arrays.binarySearch(someStringArray, "The String to find.", (a,b) -> a.compareTo(b));
```

but even before lambdas, there were always anonymous classes:

```
Arrays.binarySearch(
                someStringArray,
                "The String to find.",
                new Comparator<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                        return o1.compareTo(o2);
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 6):

Also, if you want case-insensitive comparison, in recent versions of Java the `String` class contains a `public static final` field called `CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` which is of type `Comparator<String>`, as I just recently found out. So, you can get your job done using `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`.

Comment: @tallseth this is the right answer **only** if you are interested in case-insensitive search, **and** you are using a recent version of java.  If what you need is case-sensitive search, or if you are stuck with some old version of java, then this is not the right answer for you.

Answer (score 3):

We can use the String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER comparator to compare the strings in case insensitive order.

```
Arrays.binarySearch(someStringArray, "The String to find.",String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

Answer (score 3):

To generalize the good answer of Mike Nakis with `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`, you can also use :

```
Collator.getInstance();
```

See [Collator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html)

Answer (score 1):

I find the most clean way is to use [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

Like this: `strings.sort((a, b) -> a.compareTo(b));`

---

If you want to know more—

In javascript or other functional languages, we can simply pass a function as an argument, that is, `compareTo` is itself a `Comparator`.

In java, functions are not first-class citizens. Therefore, you need to wrap it in a class that subclasses `Comparator` and define the method as the **only** method of that class.

Certainly it looks weird and verbose, b/c OOP is not designed to do something like this. *Lambda expression does exactly that (subclassing, defining the method) behind the scene, although the expression itself looks the same as in functional language.*

Answer (score -1):

Regarding Nambari's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11804763/369450) there was a mistake. If you compare values using double equal sign ***==*** program will never reach compare method, unless someone will use ***new*** keyword to create String object which is not the best practice. This might be a bit better solution:

```
public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        if (o1 == null && o2 == null){return 0;}
        if (o1 == null) { return -1;}
        if (o2 == null) { return 1;}
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
```

P.S. Thanks for comments ;)

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: How is this effectively any different from Nambari's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11804763/369450)?

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `StringUtils.compare("a", "b")`

Comment: It should be declared which package the `StringUtils` belongs to. My IDE lists 10 different ones. For me the answer works with `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils`.